# Getting Runtime Error in competitive algo challenge (SPOJ MAJOR)

Tags: c

According to the problem we have to find whether an element occurs more than n/2 times or not and then print Yes or No accordingly.
The numbers can vary from 10^-3 to 10^3.

I took an array count[2005] and then adding 1000 to each input to make 10^-3 equal to 0 i.e, -1000+1000=0 and then storing no.of occurrences of -1000 in count[0] and same for the rest elements. Therefore:

- lower limit= -1000+1000=0;
- higher limit= 1000+1000=2000;

But still I am getting memory access violation. Here is the link to the original problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/MAJOR/

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t,n,a,count[2005],max,check,temp;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
              check=0;
              scanf("%d",&n);
              for(int i=0;i<2005;i++)
                      count[i]=0;
              for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
              {
                      scanf("%d",&a);
                      temp=a+1000;
                      count[temp]++;
                      if(count[temp]>(n/2))
                      {
                                         check=1;
                                         max=temp-1000;
                                         break;
                      } 
              }
              if(check==1)
                          printf("YES %d\n",max);
              else
                  printf("NO\n");
                        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem to your code is you are not reading input fully - SPOJ demands that your program should read input fully, not break in middle.

Solution to your problem: Just take an arr of size (10^6+1) and first read all inputs and then apply algorithm. **Remember this if you break while reading input too, it will always be SIGSEGV. So, always read input fully on every programming website**.

Here is your modified code and it is ready to get AC:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int arr[1000002]; // Array of Size (10^6+2)
int main()
{
    int t,n,a,count[2005],max,check,temp,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
              check=0;
              scanf("%d",&n);
              for(int i=0;i<2005;i++)
                      count[i]=0;

              for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                       scanf("%d",&arr[i]);  // READING INPUT FULLY IN AN ARRAY
              
               for(i=0;i<n;i++)
              {
                      a=arr[i]; // Now, a=arr[i] and previous algorithm applies now 
                      temp=a+1000;
                      count[temp]++;
                      if(count[temp]>(n/2))
                      {
                                         check=1;
                                         max=temp-1000;
                                         break;
                      } 
              }
              if(check==1)
                          printf("YES %d\n",max);
              else
                  printf("NO\n");
 
    }
    return 0;
}
```